# Suspending threads of thread pool in C

Tags: multithreading, segmentation-fault, pthreads, threadpool

I am working on a project based on parallel programming, where I need to execute a given task as efficiently as possible (in terms of time and energy consumption).
For this I need to suspend some threads from the worker pool based on some conditions. These threads are created using pthread_create().

I have two types of worker pools, one stores the threads that are active and other one stores the suspended threads. After identifying the thread to be suspended, I push it's threadID into my suspended thread pool and then suspend the thread using pthread_kill.

```
push_task_suspended(threadID);
int status = pthread_kill(threadID,SIGSTOP);
```

But, I am getting a segmentation fault on using this. I have run gdb on this code, it shows segmentation fault due to pthread_kill.

Can you please tell why am I getting this?

Comment: Mixing signals and threads is a sure recipe for disaster. Have the thread-to-be-suspended block waiting for a mutex instead.

Comment: Why doesn't the thread just wait on a condition variable until it's given more work. See pthread_cond_wait.

Comment: Okay..thanks. I will try to use mutex locks.

Comment: Why are so many so determined to misuse mutex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why the `pthread_kill(threadID,SIGSTOP)` is crashing -- I guess `threadID` is not the `pthread_t` for the thread ? -- but it's definitely not a good way of dealing with the problem !

Condition variables are a bit tricky, but worth understanding.  I got a bit over excited here... but I hope it's useful.

---

**Using your own 'task_suspended' queue -- with `sema_t`**

Let's assume you have a mutex around the dequeuing of pending tasks and the enqueuing of idle workers.  Then a worker going idle must:

```
  loop:
    lock(mutex)
      .... look for task, but if none pending ....
      enqueue(self)  -- on task_suspended queue
    unlock(mutex)    -- (a)
    suspend(self)    -- (b)
    goto loop
```

And when adding a task, the logic is:

```
    lock(mutex)
      enqueue(task)  -- on task pending queue
      if (worker-idle-queue-not-empty)
        dequeue(worker)
        desuspend(worker)
    unlock(mutex)
```

In fact, the `desuspend()` does not need to be inside the `mutex`, but that's a minor matter.

What does matter is that the `desuspend()` must work even if it happens between the `unlock()` at (a) and the `suspend()` at (b).  You could give every thread its own `sem_t` semaphore -- then `suspend()` is a `sem_wait()` and `desuspend()` is `sem_post()`.  [But, no, you cannot use a mutex for this !!]

---

**Using a 'Condition Variable'**

With your own 'task_suspended' queue you are reinventing a wheel.

As mentioned in the comments, above, the tool provided for this job is the (so called) 'condition variable' -- `pthread_cond_t`.

The key to using 'condition variables' is to understand that they are ***absolutely not*** variables -- they do **not** have a value, they do **not** in any sense count the number of `pthread_cond_wait()` and/or `pthread_cond_signal()`... they are not a form of semaphore.  Despite the name, a `pthread_cond_t` is best thought of as a **queue** of threads.  And then:

```
    pthread_cond_wait(cond, mutex)  is, effectively:  enqueue(self)   -- on 'cond'
                                                      unlock(mutex)
                                                      suspend(self)
                                                      ....wait for signal...
                                                      lock(mutex)
```

where by some magic the `enqueue()`+`unlock()`+`suspend()` are a single operation (as far as all threads are concerned), and then:

```
    pthread_cond_signal(cond)  is, effectively:      if ('cond' queue-not-empty)
                                                       dequeue(thread)  -- from 'cond'
                                                       desuspend(thread)
```

where, also, by some magic that is all a single operation.  [NB: `pthread_cond_signal()` is allowed to dequeue and desuspend more than one thread, see below.]

So now, for the worker thread  we have:

```
    lock(mutex)
  loop:
      .... look for task, but if none pending ....
      pthread_cond_wait(cond, mutex)     
      goto loop
    ... if have task, pick it up ...
    unlock(mutex)
```

and for task creation:

```
    lock(mutex)
      enqueue(task)    
      pthread_cond_signal(cond)
    unlock(mutex)
```

where the `cond` takes the place of the explicit queue of pending threads.

Now, the `pthread_cond_signal(cond)` can be inside or outside the `mutex`.  If inside, then conceptually, as soon as a thread is dequeued from the `cond` queue it will run and immediately block on the mutex -- which seems like a waste.  But the implementation could do something clever, and simply transfer the restarted thread(s) from one queue to another.

Note that the task creator does not know how many suspended threads there are, nor does it care.  POSIX says the pthread_cond_signal() function shall:

> - ...unblock at least one of the threads that are blocked on the specified condition variable *cond* (if any threads are blocked on *cond*).
> - ...have no effect if there are no threads currently blocked on *cond*.

Note especially "unblock **at least** one of the threads".  Again, it is a mistake to think of a `cond` as a variable.  It is a mistake to think of a `cond` as (say) a "task ready" flag, or a count, or anything else you might think of as being a variable.  It just isn't so.  When a thread restarts after a `pthread_cond_wait()` what it was waiting for may or may not have occurred, and if it has, another thread may have got there first.  This is why everything you read about (so called) 'condition variables' will talk of using them inside a loop, and returning to the top of the loop (just after the `lock(mutex)`) on return from the `pthread_cond_wait()`.

NB: when a thread restarts after a `pthread_cond_wait()` it may be one of several restarted by a single `pthread_cond_signal()`, and yes it seems odd that POSIX allows that -- presumably either to fit with some historic implementation, or to allow for some simpler implementation (perhaps related to thread priority).  But, even if `pthread_cond_wait()` did guarantee to restart just one thread, the restarted thread could regain the mutex *after* some other worker thread, thus:

```
     Worker 1               |  Worker 2               |  Task Queue
       busy                 |    busy                 |    empty
       lock(mutex)          |    .                    |    .
       + task queue empty   |    .                    |    lock(mutex)
       unlock(mutex) +      |    .                    |    -
                 wait(cond) |    .                    |    -
       ~                    |    lock(mutex)          |    + enqueue task
       ~                    |    -                    |    + signal(cond)
       re-lock(mutex)       |    -                    |    unlock(mutex)                      
       -                    |    + dequeue task       |    .
       -                    |    unlock(mutex)        |    empty
       + task queue empty ! |    busy                 |    .
```

where `+` is where the thread owns the mutex, `-` is where it is waiting for the mutex, and `~` is where it is waiting for the 'cond' to be signaled.

You could be worried about doing `pthread_cond_signal(cond)` every time a new task is enqueued... so you could do that only when the task queue was empty.  You should be able to convince yourself that works -- particularly if done inside the mutex.

---

**Using a `sem_t` or a `sem_t` with a counter**

Alternatively, you could use a `sem_t` to count the number of 'tasks - waiters'.  Each time a new task is added to the queue, the semaphore is incremented (sem_post).  Each time a worker completes a task, it reserves the next task or waits (sem_wait).  You still need a safe way to enqueue and dequeue tasks -- say: lock(mutex), enqueue(task), unlock(mutex), post(sem); and: wait(sem), lock(mutex), dequeue(task), unlock(mutex).

The only difficulty here is that the maximum value of a semaphore can be as small as 32767 -- see `sysconf(_SC_SEM_VALUE_MAX)`.

Or you could use one `sem_t` and a count of waiters.  So, for the worker thread we have:

```
  loop:
    lock(mutex)
      .... look for task, but if none pending ....
      increment waiter-count
    unlock(mutex)
    sem_wait(sem)
    goto loop
```

and for task creation:

```
    lock(mutex)
      enqueue(task)    
      kick = (waiter-count != 0)
      if (kick)
        decrement(waiter-count)
    unlock(mutex)
    if (kick)
      sem_post(sem)
```

The `sem_post()` can be put inside the mutex -- but is better outside.

And you are OK unless you have more than 32767 worker threads (!).

But, when you un-pick this, you will see that this is (largely) reinventing `pthread_cond_wait`/ `_signal()`, and not likely to be any more efficient.

Comment: Thanks a lot for such elaborated explanation. It cleared many of my doubts!!

Answer (score 0):

I don't agree with previous posters that signals generally can't be used with threads. You just have to do it with caution.

The disadvantage of solutions using condition variables, mutexes, or semaphores is that the thread isn't paused immediately, and requires active checking on the part of the thread to be stopped. You can achieve an immediate stop using signals. You just can't use `SIGSTOP`.

`pthread_kill(threaID, SIGSTOP)` stops the entire process and thus the **caller**, too, which is probably not intended, and you can't do anything about that. The Linux **pthread_kill(3)** man page says "*if a signal handler is installed, the handler will be invoked in the thread `thread`, but if the disposition of the signal is "stop", "continue", or "terminate", this action will affect the whole process*", and the **signal(7)** man page specifies that the disposition of `SIGSTOP` can't be changed.

But you can use different signals instead, for example `SIGUSR1` for "stop thread" and `SIGUSR2` for "continue thread". You *must catch* these signals (to avoid using a default disposition), and make sure that the to-be-stopped thread doesn't block them. Of course, signals must be sent with `pthread_kill()`.

The signal handler for the "stop thread" signal calls `pause()` or some other function that waits indefinitely. A later "continue thread" signal (in fact, any caught signal that isn't blocked) will interrupt the `pause()` call, the "stop thread" signal handler will return, and the thread will resume execution.

The general rule when using threads and signals is "*block everything*". Threads should unblock only signals they strictly need to react on. Standard signals like `SIGTERM`, `SIGINT`, `SIGCHLD`, which might be sent to the application from outside, should be blocked in all but one dedicated thread. When a termination signal is received, this thread should take care of terminating the other threads, either using `pthread_cancel()` or by sending an application-defined signal.